# If $f$ is surjective from $A$ to $B$ and $A$ is well-orderable, then $B$ is well-orderable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

I think the logic is correct, but I would greatly appreciate any pointers. In particular, the way in which I defined my function relies on a cumbersome FOL statement, which I would like to avoid (as I have seen recommendations from more experienced individuals to reduce the formalisms).

---

**Given**:

$f$ is a surjective function from $A$ to $B$. $\quad f:A\xrightarrow[\text{onto}]{} B$

$A$ is *well-orderable*. That means there is a relation $R$ that well-orders $A$.

**Claim to Prove**:

> Show that $B$ is well-orderable (i.e. show that there exists a relation that well-orders $B$)

**Definition in my book:** $R$ well-orders $A$ *iff* $R$ totally orders $A$ strictly and $R$ is *well-founded* on $A$.

---

Importantly, one can demonstrate that all subsets of a well-ordered set are *also* well-ordered.

Because $f$ is surjective and $A$ is well-ordered by $R$: $\forall b \in B\ \    \exists! a' \in A \Big (f(a')=b \ \ \land \ \ \forall a \in A\  [f(a)=b \rightarrow a \not R a'] \Big)$.

That is to say: for a given $b$, of the element(s) from $A$ that map to $b$, there is always one minimum element $a'$ that is taken to $b$ through $f$ .

Let $g(b)$ map to this unique $a'$.

So we have:

$g: B \to A$ where $b \mapsto a'$

---

$g$ can be shown to be injective. Let $b_1 \neq b_2$. By definition, $g(b_1)=a_1'$ and $g(b_2)=a_2'$, where $f(a_1')=b_1$ and $f(a_2')=b_2.$ If $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$, then we see that $f$ maps the same element in $A$ to two different (non-equal) elements in $B$. $f$ is a function so this is a contradiction.

To ensure that $g$ is surjective, the codomain can be modified so that:

$g: B \xrightarrow[\text{onto}]{1-1}g[B]$, where $g[B] \subseteq A$. Thus, $g$ is a bijection.

Define a new relation $R'$ as follows:

$\forall b_1, b_2 \in B\ [b_1 \ R' \ b_2 \leftrightarrow g(b_1)\ R \ g(b_2)]$

$R'$ therefore inherits all of the "well-orderedness" of $g[B]$, which is a subset of the well-ordered set $A$.

$R'$ well-orders $B$ $\quad \square$

Comment: Please, could you prove that any subset of a well-ordered set is also well-ordered?

Comment: @Angelo based off the answer below, it seems like there may be a difference in the definition I am using. In my book (by Kenneth Kunen), well-ordered is defined as a set that has a strict total ordering and is well-founded, where well-founded is the definition that "dbx" posted below for well-ordered.

Comment: @Angelo if your question is directed toward the Kenneth Kunen definition of well-ordered, I can provide a proof.

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof is quite complicated, much more so than necessary.

*Defn*: A set $A$ is well-ordered (under $<$) if every nonempty subset of $A$ has a least element with respect to $<$.

*Thm*: If $A$ is well-ordered and $f:A\rightarrow B$ is surjective, then $B$ has a well-ordering.

*Proof*: We can demonstrate such a well-ordering directly. For each $b \in B$, $f^{-1}(b)$ is nonempty by the surjectivity of $f$. Define $a_b$ to be the smallest element of $f^{-1}(b)$, which is guaranteed to exist by the well-ordering of $A$.

For $b_1$ and $b_2$ in $B$, define $b_1 \prec b_2$ iff $a_{b_1} < a_{b_2}$. We claim that $\prec$ is a well-ordering of $B$:

Suppose $X$ is any nonempty subset of $B$, and let $a_X = \{ a_b \mid b \in X \}$. Since $A$ is well-ordered, $a_X$ has a least element, call it $a_\ell$. Then by definition of $\prec$, we see that $b_\ell = f(a_\ell)$ is the least element of $X$. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you for the input. For clarification to the readers, my book distinguishes between *well-ordered* and *well-founded*. Not that it really matters because the proofs would be identical (I believe), but *well-ordered* is defined in my book as: "A strict total order that is well-founded", where well-founded is the definition you provided for well-ordered.

Comment: (technically you'd have to show trichotomy, irreflexivity, and transitivity as well...but those are quickly demonstrated from the biconditional definition of the $\prec$ relation)